# Inconsisntently growing indices in Elasticc

Tags: elasticsearch, logging

I've come across a problem where indices after a specific date became 5-8 times larger.
For example, indices that were around 2-3GB in size became 16-27GB without apparent reason.
The only solution I've figured out is to divide index logstash into indices ${service_1} ${service_2} etc. My analysis of the problem proved to be insufficient for the matter where I couldn't analyze logs to the extent of nitpicking the problematic service so I stick to the idea of dividing index. Do you have any other suggestions that might prove to be useful? I'll attach screenshots for better understanding of the problem. Thanks[image]
[image: As you can see there's no clear consistency between document volume and index size]

As per Val's suggestion I'm posting the zero-day of the problem info:
The day before the problem

```
index                           shard prirep ip        segment generation docs.count docs.deleted     size size.memory committed searchable version compound
logstash-2022.10.27             0     p      127.0.0.1 _q7g         33964   10755243            0    4.9gb      224396 true      true       8.11.1  false
logstash-2022.10.27             0     p      127.0.0.1 _syo         37536     776441            0  264.1mb      184580 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.27             0     p      127.0.0.1 _vgy         40786     566669            0  198.7mb      114652 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.27             0     p      127.0.0.1 _z9f         45699     680144            0  246.2mb      126068 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.27             0     p      127.0.0.1 _11j2        48638      26702            0    9.7mb       44388 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.27             0     p      127.0.0.1 _11ss        48988      51187            0   16.6mb       59164 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.27             0     p      127.0.0.1 _122b        49331      41226            0   18.1mb       59908 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.27             0     p      127.0.0.1 _12w9        50409      19824            0    8.6mb       41980 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.27             0     p      127.0.0.1 _12xd        50449    1952871            0  703.2mb      198180 true      true       8.11.1  false
logstash-2022.10.27             0     p      127.0.0.1 _13k9        51273      72041            0   23.6mb       93308 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.27             0     p      127.0.0.1 _13qw        51512     110195            0   43.2mb       89260 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.27             0     p      127.0.0.1 _14c7        52279      53878            0   16.8mb       93804 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.27             0     p      127.0.0.1 _14hs        52480      37872            0   14.6mb       74436 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.27             0     p      127.0.0.1 _14k9        52569     124164            0     43mb       94852 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.27             0     p      127.0.0.1 _14u1        52921       8166            0    3.3mb       44740 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.27             0     p      127.0.0.1 _14v7        52963       8093            0    3.1mb       53868 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.27             0     p      127.0.0.1 _14vy        52990       6863            0    3.1mb       51148 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.27             0     p      127.0.0.1 _14xm        53050      31999            0   10.5mb       58660 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.27             0     p      127.0.0.1 _153g        53260       8823            0      2mb       54076 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.27             0     p      127.0.0.1 _154a        53290      10375            0      2mb       40436 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.27             0     p      127.0.0.1 _156i        53370       7633            0    1.8mb       52684 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.27             0     p      127.0.0.1 _156t        53381        159            0  167.2kb       35060 true      true       8.11.1  true
```

The day of the problem:

```
index                           shard prirep ip        segment generation docs.count docs.deleted     size size.memory committed searchable version compound
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _dur         17955    5309645            0    4.8gb      224212 true      true       8.11.1  false
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _i7z         23615    3296729            0    4.7gb      215972 true      true       8.11.1  false
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _mbh         28925    3524971            0    4.7gb      215188 true      true       8.11.1  false
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _o8a         31402    1192613            0    1.4gb      206940 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _oj4         31792     177752            0   83.1mb      183860 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _ooq         31994     215416            0  230.7mb      183612 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _qer         34227     149495            0  124.2mb      175460 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _r3r         35127     534117            0  360.2mb      193308 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _svv         37435     375931            0  213.7mb      171844 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _vft         40745     122376            0   69.3mb       88892 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _wax         41865     986553            0  385.7mb      156684 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _y49         44217     176553            0   63.8mb       87388 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _zlb         46127     177922            0   61.7mb       83284 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _10hh        47285     571840            0  188.2mb      100188 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _125r        49455     663923            0  248.4mb      104716 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _12v1        50365      98001            0   42.2mb       66452 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _131h        50597      54027            0   22.8mb       42724 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _13kv        51295     225678            0   69.9mb       80516 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _13qq        51506      14069            0    6.2mb       51764 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _13rk        51536      19878            0    8.1mb       40348 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _13se        51566      51651            0   21.6mb       60468 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _13xd        51745      62558            0   27.4mb       59908 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _148h        52145      11920            0    2.1mb       31612 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _149l        52185      18585            0    2.8mb       43116 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _14b9        52245       9218            0    2.2mb       45292 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _14bt        52265       8416            0    2.1mb       52548 true      true       8.11.1  true
logstash-2022.10.28             0     p      127.0.0.1 _14bu        52266         12            0     41kb       16020 true      true       8.11.1  true
```

Comment: Are those indexes constantly being written to? What can you say about the number of documents (and also deleted documents) before/after? If you can reproduce this, can you run `GET _cat/indices?v` before and after?

Comment: @Val Index is time-date based so it's readonly after a day. I don't really know about deleting documents from indices, we don't do that manually either. The problem only occurs on PROD environment on test everything is same as before indices are no bigger than 3GB. I can give _cat/indices?v but I can't reproduce the problem since it's a daily occurance. It's just seems to me that developer's team modified logs at some point and they can't bactrack what exaclty they changed and when which is quite bothersome.

Comment: Ok then if it happens in prod, you can run `GET _cat/indices?v` now and again in a few days once you notice the same problem occurs.

Comment: Do you have a way to analyse the issue? It's not that number of documents is growing but the space they take up. I'll follow your advice and post a followup in a few days!

Comment: If you can run `GET _cat/indices?v&s=i:asc` + `GET _cat/shards?v&s=i:asc` + `GET _cat/segments?v&s=i:asc` now and later when the problem shows up, it's going to be interesting to see the differences

Comment: I have an example of inconsistency now, do I post it in the question or comments? It's very apparent in every section that you metioned and is also the zero day of the problem.

Comment: You can update your question

Comment: @Val I updated the question with segment section. It looks most eficcient information-wise

Comment: But the before/after are not the same index, `logstash-2022.10.27` vs `logstash-2022.10.28`. We need to compare the same index before and after the problem happens

Comment: So I need to do cat-ing every now and then and collect info real-time?

Comment: Well, we need to be able to understand how and why your logstash indexes are growing, so we need to compare their state at the some point and at some later point.

Comment: That's the least I can do :)